# Excel 2.1 Connection String

Tags: excel, connection-string

Hi I have a legacy application that spits out an excel 2.1 file *.xls I have a requirement to open this file and extract some of the fields out the problem is I cant seem to find a connection string for this version

I have been using something like

exconnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= c:\test.xls ;Extended Properties=Excel 2.1"

I have tried Excel 5 and Excel 8 but they all give errors

Any one know a way around this other than opening the file in excel manually

```
    Dim exconnectionString As String
    exconnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Dts.Variables("conf_file_source").Value + FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 1.0;"


    Dim conexcel As New OleDbConnection(exconnectionString)
    conexcel.Open()
```

I get the error when opening OLEDB connection

when trying excel 1.0 or 2.1
get the following error

**Could not find installable ISAM**

when trying with excel 3.0 or higher 
get the following error

**external table is not in the expected format**

Thanks Much

Comment: ` I have a requirement to open this file and extract some of the fields out`, Have you tried to Open the file then extract the fields out? Also sometimes with older Files types (2003 and earlier) the connection string needs to be prefixed with `OLEDB;` Or ned to end with a `;` so your CS would become `"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= c:\test.xls ;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"` OR `"OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= c:\test.xls ;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"`

Comment: my mistake I missed the ; when opening the inquiry my connection string does end with a ; (editing my original inquiry to reflect this)will also try starting it with OLEDB shortly

Comment: just tried starting CS with OLEDB but error "an OLE DB provider was not specified in the connectionstring" ... and yes I am trying to open the file programmatically first before I do any extracts all the extracting code works for excel files 97 and newer just have a problem with the connection string for excel 2.1 versions

Comment: Which OS you are working with?

Comment: @Jaju windows server 2008 R2 ... I am using the code from inside an SSIS 2008 script task